# UIPanGestureRecognizer conflict with constraints animation

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I have an animation of a contentView of a cell wish have UIPanGestureRecognizer.

the UIPanGestureRecognizer works fine and detect touches but while the animation is happening it doesn't detect touches  until it finish the animation.

is there a workaround for this.

this is the animation block

```
[self.myContentView layoutIfNeeded];
self.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant = -50;
self.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = 50;

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    [self.myContentView layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:completion];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allow user interaction during the animation, you must set the option to allow it:

```
UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut |
    UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:options animations:^{
    [self.myContentView layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:completion];
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
You saved my day :)